# Prove that $2017$ is a divisor of $2016!(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $x$ be an integer such that $2017$ is a divisor of $x^2+x+1$ . Prove that $2017$ is a divisor of  $2016!(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016})$.

We define "segment congruence" : $\frac{a}{b}\equiv  \frac{c}{d} (\mod 2017)$ if and only if $ad \equiv bc (\mod 2017)$

So to prove that $2017$ is a divisor of  $2016!(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016})$ , we only need to prove $(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016}) \equiv 0 ( \mod 2017)$

$2017$ is a divisor of $x^2+x+1 \Rightarrow x^3 \equiv 1 \mod 2017$

$\Rightarrow -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^5}{5} -...+ \frac{x^{2015}}{2015} \equiv x^2 (-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{5}-...+\frac{1}{2015} )\mod 2017$

$x-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^{10}}{10}+....-\frac{x^{2014}}{2014} \equiv x( 1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+...-\frac{1}{2014}) \mod 2017$

$\frac{x^3}{3}- \frac{x^6}{6} -....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016} \equiv \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6} +\frac{1}{9}-...-\frac{1}{2016} \mod 2017$

We have $( 1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+...-\frac{1}{2014})-(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6} +\frac{1}{9}-...-\frac{1}{2016}) = (\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2016} -\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2013}-...-\frac{1}{2014}-\frac{1}{3}) \equiv 2017 \frac{c}{d} \equiv 0 \mod 2017$

$\Rightarrow ( 1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+...-\frac{1}{2014}) \equiv (\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6} +\frac{1}{9}-...-\frac{1}{2016}) \mod 2017 $

So to prove $(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-....-\frac{x^{2016}}{2016}) \equiv 0 ( \mod 2017)$ , we only need to prove  $-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{5}-...+\frac{1}{2015} \equiv  1 -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{10}+...-\frac{1}{2014} \equiv \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6} +\frac{1}{9}-...-\frac{1}{2016} \mod 2017 $

But I don't have any idea yet, hope to get your help. Thank you very much !

Comment: The reason why $2016!$ is required is because the other term isn't even an integer necessarily : so one cannot ignore the role of the $2016!$ even if it's coprime to $2017$.

Comment: instead of 2017, try it for prime 7, then prime 13.   I'm not sure about 7 because it is not $1 \pmod 4,$  that could matter   as you have the alternating $\pm$ signs

Comment: Note: Moving to $ x^3 \equiv 1 $ will not work, because $ x \equiv 1 $ doesn't satisfy the condition (IE Or at the very least, you'd have to account for that separately). The condition is satisfied for $ x = -1$, but that doesn't seem to simplify the expression.

Comment: See [these solutions to ELMO 2009 P6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h514444p2890151).

Comment: The binomial identity used in the proofs in the document above were extremely useful. I wonder if there is a way of working while avoiding that particular identity.